# "Não poder" pode significar algo como "poder não"?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, concordância-negativa

É possível formar uma frase que usa "não poder" para significar, em vez da *impossibilidade* duma coisa, a *possibilidade* daquela coisa *não* ser?

Por exemplo, se "Eu não posso estar aqui amanhã" (ou algo similar) podia significar "Talvez não vou estar aqui amanhã", em vez de "Com certeza não vou estar aqui amanhã, porque não posso". Entendo que "posso não estar" tem este significado, mas quero saber se "não posso estar" pode ter este significado também.

Sempre pensei que eu tive de encontrar este uso de "não poder", mas alguém me diz que não existe. Talvez me enganei de alguma forma. Existe este uso ou não?

Se por ocaso existe, a minha pergunta seguinte seria: Há forma de distinguir entre estes significados quase opostos na gramática?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Não posso estar aqui amanhã” significa apenas ’é-me impossível estar aqui amanhã’. Não vejo nenhuma situação em que possa significar ’existe a possibilidade de eu não estar’. (Poderia significar ’tenho o dever de não estar aqui amanhã’, mas creio que a tua questão não esta.)

“Posso não estar aqui amanhã” é que significa normalmente ’existe a possibilidade de eu não estar aqui amanhã’. Mas isto, dependendo do contexto, pode significar coisas diferentes. Por exemplo:

> Paulo à Ana — A Beatriz vem cá amanhã e gostava de te ver.
>
> Ana — Eu posso não estar cá amanhã.

Aqui subentende-se qualquer coisa como ’ainda não sei se cá vou estar ou não amanhã (ainda não sei como é que vai ser a minha vida amanhã)’. Agora nesta outra situação:

> Paulo à Joana — A Beatriz vem cá amanhã e não vai gostar nada de te ver.
>
> Joana — Eu posso não estar cá amanhã.

Aqui isto poderia significar o mesmo que em cima (’ainda não sei’) ou ’eu posso escolher não estar cá amanhã (se achares melhor, não venho cá)’. Neste caso, o contexto, expressão facial e entoação é que poderão desambiguar completamente.

---

A *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (Lisboa, 2013, tomo I, p. 654-5) confirma que isto é geral:

> Em frases com verbos semiauxiliares modais, a negação pode preceder o verbo; nesse caso, semanticamente, incide (ou **tem escopo**) sobre todo o predicado (incluindo o verbo modal) […] A negação pode seguir o verbo modal, tendo, neste caso, escopo sobre o predicado que segue o verbo modal, mas não sobre o próprio modal

No caso do verbo *poder*, a *Gramática* ilustra com “os miúdos [’garotos’] *não* podem ler este livro”, que significa que eles “não são capazes”, ou que “as circunstâncias não permitem”, ou que eles “não têm permissão”. Enquanto em “os miúdos podem não ler o livro” são possíveis uma “leitura epistémica” (não se sabe se eles vão ler ou não) ou uma “leitura deôntica” (eles têm permissão para não ler). Embora, digo eu, nos contexto mais comuns, a maneira mais natural de exprimir a leitura deôntica seria “eles não têm de ler este livro” ou “não precisam de ler este livro”.